# Is it possible to tetrahedral a mesh in Blender?

Tags: python, mesh

I have a mesh and I want to tetrahedral it (create a volume inside this big surface, important for the volume rendering), using a script in Python.
After days of research, I found someone who suggested the TetGen software, or the GAMer library. I found something about the FEM method and the Delaunay algorithm...But now I just have a big confusion.
Probably the problem is my ignorance of this subject.

This is my script (it doesn't work) and my mesh (it is only an "empty shell").

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from bmesh.types import BMVert 

# The mesh and its related object
obj = bpy.context.active_object
me = obj.data

# Access to BMesh data and ensure lookup tables
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

# Geometry to extrude
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
faces = [bm.faces]

# Extrude mesh with Bmesh
for f,triangle in zip(faces,me.polygons):
    newGeom = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom = f)
    
    # Move the extruded geometry with translate operator
    extruded_verts = [v for v in newGeom['geom'] if isinstance(v,BMVert)]
    up = triangle.normal
    bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec = up, verts = extruded_verts)


bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Mesh:  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=BBmorMmw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/BBmorMmw/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you should replace:

- `faces = [bm.faces]` by `faces = bm.faces[:]` because you want an array of face, not an array with one array of faces.
- `geom = f` by `geom = [f]` in consequence

Though, using bmesh.ops too many times will lead to poor performance.

You can extrude all in [one operation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces) and loop over the result for just shifting the coordinates:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from bmesh.types import BMVert 

# The mesh and its related object
obj = bpy.context.active_object
me = obj.data

# Access to BMesh data and ensure lookup tables
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

# Geometry to extrude
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
faces = bm.faces[:]

# Extrude once
result = bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces(bm, faces = faces)

for face in result["faces"]:
    up = face.normal
    #Shift the vertices without bmesh.ops
    for v in face.verts:
        v.co += up

bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

Which gives:

[image]